# 'NSError' is not supported as an RLMObject property. All properties must be primitives

Tags: swift2, xcode7, realm, nserror

my app is crashing and is returning me this error on the console. My build works fine but when I try to run unit tests I get this.

> 'NSError' is not supported as an RLMObject property. All properties must be primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, RLMArray, or subclasses of RLMObject

this is what my model looks like...

```
public class Place: Object {

// mongo id
public dynamic var _id: String = ""
// google id
public dynamic var google_id: String = ""
// name
public dynamic var name: String = ""
// score
public dynamic var score: Double = 0
// types
public let types = List<TypeObject>()
public dynamic var typeFormat: String = ""
// address
public dynamic var address: Address?
// geographic location
public dynamic var location: GeoJSON?
// phone
public dynamic var phone: Phone?
// open now
public dynamic var openNow: Bool = false
// hours
public let hours = List<Hours>()
// utc offset
public dynamic var utcOffset: Int = 0
// website
public dynamic var website: String = ""
// price level
public dynamic var priceLevel: Int = 0
// created at, updated at
public dynamic var createdAt: String = ""
public dynamic var updatedAt: String = ""
// visit
public let history = List<Visit>()
public dynamic var visitValue: VisitValue?
public dynamic var voteValue: VoteValue?
// reviews
public let reviews = List<Review>()
// photos
public let photos = List<Photo>()

...
```

the model class is huge so I omitted the initializers. One thing to note, is that this class does not contain any NSError types but contains functions, getters, and setters, all of which do not throw any sort of errors. I don't know if that affects the model at all but they have all been working fine up this point. All these errors started happening when I upgrade to Swift 2 and XCode 7. I'm really stumped over here, any help would be great.

**UPDATE**
my problem was that I added a `var error: NSError?` accidentally in between two functions within my model while I was optimizing code. I couldn't find it because my model is packed with helper functions and what not. So I hope this helps anyone who runs into this problem to just leave models alone and put any code that isn't schema related outside of the model itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add an "Exception Breakpoint"? If so, you can then figure out which property in your model is causing the issue based off of the `name` variable passed into this method in `RLMProperty.mm`:

```c
initSwiftPropertyWithName:indexed:property:instance:
```

which is ultimately calling `setTypeFromRawType` which is where the error is generated.

My guess is it is one of the object relationship properties because the error occurs when it is evaluating your model and checking if the property points to a subclass of Realm `Object`.

Comment: I added a NSLog in that function you said (thanks for that), and this is what I got... `2015-09-30 20:54:51.885 Fomo[98378:331319] error
2015-09-30 20:54:51.885 Fomo[98378:331319] (null) {` so that means that there is a variable of a NSError type in my Object schema?

Comment: wow thanks a lot for this comment, it really helped. I had to go through all my schemas and looked for a variable named 'error', I found it wedged in between two functions. I accidentally wrote it there thinking it was still within the function scope. This bug took me the whole day -____- I'm just the biggest dummy apparently.

Comment: Sorry didn't get to this sooner, but glad you figured it out!